# Make a database column not editable

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I make a SQL database column not editable?

I want to be able to insert, but on update, that column should not be allowed to change.

I know this can be achieved using a trigger on update, however is there any more elegant solution?

Preferably using Entity Framework Core or Oracle, but I am interested in whatever technologies for educational purposes anyway.

Comment: So is this Oracle you are using?

Comment: EF core with oracle

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about the business rule you're trying to enforce? Why do you what immutable columns? Not saying it's an unreasonable request, just that it would be easier to provide an answer if we understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no declarative mechanism for fixing the value of a column. The only way is doing it programmatically with a trigger. Triggers give us the ability to compare `:old` and `:new` values of a column during an update event, and take action if they differ.

Here's the most straightforward approach:

```
create or replace trigger trg23 before update on t23 for each row
begin
  if :old.col1 <> :new.col1 then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'You cannot change COL1!');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Here is a terser version of the same trigger, which only fires when we try to update COL1:

```
create or replace trigger trg23 before update of col1 on t23 for each row
begin
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'You really cannot change COL1!');
end;
/
```

By specifying the column name in the trigger spec we can make the trigger body really spartan. This is as close to elegant as we can get.

Triggers also give us the ability to silently suppress the change. This seems like an attractive option, as it follows the unix model of only raising exceptions in truly exceptional circumstances. But in my experience users can be confused when the computer "loses" their changes without explanation.

```
create or replace trigger trg23 before update on t23 for each row
begin
  :new.col1 := :old.col1;
end;
/
```

Here is [a db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=503435afbdc533a8e1f330cf3d39fb28) of these triggers in action.

---

The above answer presumes that our users can insert **anything** for the original value but just cannot change it, for some peculiar business reason. But if the column must be immutable because its value is fixed or derived then maybe a virtual column is what you need.

This table has a fixed value for the `subtype` column:

```
create table t69 (id number primary key 
                  , subtype varchar2(4) generated always as ('ACCT')
                  , credit_limit number )
/
```

We cannot update the subtype:

```
update t69
set subtype = 'CUST'
where id = 1234
/
```

This is a useful construct for implementing super-type/sub-type entities in a logical model.

Virtual columns are also useful for providing user-friendly smart keys whilst maintaining first normal form. This example shows how we can derive the business key EVENT_REF from its constituent parts:

```
create table t42 (deptid varchar2(2) not null
                  , create_dt date not null
                  , serial_no number not null
                  , event_ref varchar2(32) generated always as (deptid || '\' || to_char(create_dt, 'yyyymm') || '\' || to_char(serial_no, 'fm0000000'))
)
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for this type of requirement is **VPD(virtual private database)** as you dont want to use triggers.

By applying `VPD` on table, you will be able to add transparent where clause to any type of statement.

You just need to create `VPD` on table with `function` as following, assuming your table name as `MY_TABLE` and non-updatable column name is `MY_COL`:

```
create function my_table_vpd_fun return varchar2 deterministic
as
    return '1=0';
end;
/

begin
  dbms_rls.add_policy (
     object_name       => 'MY_TABLE' -- your table name goes here
    ,policy_name       => 'MY_TABLE_UPDATE_VPD'
    ,policy_function   => 'MY_TABLE_VPD_FUN'
    ,statement_types   => 'UPDATE'
    ,static_policy     => 'TRUE'
    ,sec_relevent_cols => 'MY_COL' -- your column name goes here
  );
end;
/
```

Whenever `MY_COL` is used in `UPDATE` of `MY_TABLE`, this `VPD` will apply `1=0` condition. Hence whole statement will not update anything (may be bad news for you). If `MY_COL` is not referenced in update statement, this `VPD` will not apply `where` condition and allows updates on any other columns.

But yes, `VPD` concept is good if fits into your requirement.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the application(s) do not directly connect to the owner of the table, instead, make them connect to a separate user (e.g. `APP`).
2. Create an updateable view on the table. Grant SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE (as needed) on the view to `APP`.
3. Create an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view to translate inserts, updates and deletes to the underlying table. The PL/SQL in the trigger can ignore that column for updates, or raise an exception if you want it to detect an attempt to modify the column.